# add JProgressBar and JLabel vertically in JToolbar

Tags: java, swing

```
analysisProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
analysisProgressLabel = new JLabel("Analysing...");

add(analysisProgressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(analysisProgressLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

How can I add `JProgressBar` and `JLabel` vertically in `JToolBar`?
I want it to look like this:

```
[====              ]

     Analysing...
```

How it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p.add(analysisProgressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
p.add(analysisProgressLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
toolbar.add(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over the layout, maybe consider using a `GridBagLayout`

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
add(analysisProgressBar, gbc);
add(analysisProgressLabel, gbc);
```

this may generate a better result when the container is resized

Have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)